# iPad portrait / langscape - no iPad recognition with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ipad, responsive-design

I want to be able to set different viewport meta tags, depending on whether the device is iPad or not, and if it's iPad, whether it's being used in portrait or landscape view.

It should be doable with JavaScript, thanks to Apple's iPad user agent string, as described in this [article by David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ipad).

Something like this:

```
if isiPad and max-width=768px -> use viewport meta for portrait
else if isiPad and max-width=1024px -> use some viewport meta for landscape
else (not iPad) -> use default viewport meta for non-iPad devices;
also (some kind of event listener) if ipad's max-width changes from 768 to 1024, or from 1024 to 768 - use corresponding viewport meta.
```

Could someone skillful translate this into actual JavaScript?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var isIpad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/) != null;
if (isIpad) {
    var meta = document.createElement("meta");
    meta.setAttribute("viewport", "whatever");
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.appendChild(meta);
} else {
    // etc..
};

window.onresize = function(event) {
    var width = window.clientWidth; // This works for Android + iOS.
    var meta = document.createElement("meta");
    meta.setAttribute("viewport", "whatever");
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    for (var i = 0, i < metas.length; i++) {
         if (metas[i].getAttribute("whatever") == "blabla")//removal condition
             head.removeChild(metas[i]);
    };
    head.appendChild(meta);

};
```

Comment: This is a great step in the right direction, @alex23, thank you! – but my question was a little more specific. I want to be able to set different viewport meta tags for iPad portrait, iPad landscape, and no-iPad devices, not to style someDiv (for which media queries would probably be much more natural choice). Also, to change the viewport meta tags when the user rotates the iPad (therevy changing the device width) Is it possible to revise your script to make it do what i'm describing?

Comment: Looks like another great (but incomplete) step, @alex23, thank you! My questions, as before: a) how do I apply different viewport meta to different device-width (portrait or landscape); and b) how do I change the viewport meta on the fly when the device width changes after the web page had been initially accessed? I'd be enormously grateful for your input!

Comment: Thank you, @alex23, I can Google the things you mentioned, but that still doesn't answer my question about what happens when a user rotates the iPad and the window width changes on the fly. Isn't there supposed to be some kind of event listener included in the script? Could you please recommend, what specific thing(s) I should Google in order to apply different viewport meta tags when a user changes the window width?

Comment: Excellent, @alex23 – thank you! Would that code still work if width variable is set as global, outside of the onresize function (so that the same variable can be used to set the initial condition for portrait or landscape in the first chunk of code)?